# Css unwanted right margin, sticky footer not fixed

Tags: wordpress, css, sticky-footer

On my site I've got unwanted white margin on the right side, I don't know why. All containers on my site are contained-fluid, and also I added to my css no padding and no margins for containers.

```
  html,
page {
    width: 100%!important;
     margin:0;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    color:#333;


}
container, container-fluid {
width:100%0!important;
padding:0!important;
margin:0!important;
}
```

I'd like to put a footer on down of  site, I tried with position: absolute and margin-bottom, also tried overflow hidden but it doesn't work for me.

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse  navbottom">



   .navbottom {

background: url(../img/footer.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-color:#679003;



-moz-border-radius:0px;
border-radius: 0px;
border-style: none;
position: relative;
  margin-top: -50px; /* negative value of footer height */
  height: 50px;
  clear:both;
  padding-top:20px;
overflow:hidden;
margin-bottom:0!important;
```

full html and css
https://jsbin.com/biwuyewipi/edit?html,css,output

site:
http://fotozorza.pl/

Answer (score 0):

Firefox inspector tells me that this is your top nav bar. I am not familiar with Wordpress, so sorry that I am not able to help you more.

Also inspector says, that the rest is fine.

Answer (score 0):

this is because of google map width change it to 98vw.

EDIT :
 add following snippet to css

```
.row{ margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px; }
```

and reduce the width of google map i_frame. this is the cause of problem.